# Any experience using a SQL Server Linked Server to DB2 with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-4, db2

Unfortunately, we have to use data from a DB2 mainframe in several of our web applications. We are using Entity Framework for any data stored in SQL Server, and we would love to be able to use EF for all of our data access.

I know that IBM is working on an EF provider, but I have been following that bug-ridden mess and I don't even want to touch it.

So the next option seems to be setting up linked servers. This has worked well for other situations in the past, but I have never tried it with Entity Framework.

Has anyone out there ever tried this, and been successful? If so, could you please share your pain points and any tips and tricks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might not get it well, because I don't have any exp with EF, but if you can create LINKED server then why not create data model directly from server? and if your LINKED server will be used in Procedures then what is the big deal? It will work as it is working with other ORMs or procedure calls?

Comment: @Muhammed, the reason for the linked server is that DB2 does not yet have a viable Entity Framework provider. Using a linked server would allow us to use EF, since the data source would be a SQL Server database instead of a DB2 mainframe whatever.

Comment: Thanks @camainc, my mistake. Did not go through question throughly. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I do the same thing. Sometimes it's hard to slow down...

Answer (score 2):

Hide the linked servers behind views or stored procedures. Hopefully EF should not realise...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was hoping to hear from someone who had actually done this ;-)

Comment: @camainc: I have used linked servers to DB2, but they were hidden behind stored procs for all clients. I don't think EF will deal with OPENQUERY calls

Comment: This turned out to be far more trouble than its worth. EF sees views as read only by default, and you have to jump through a lot of hoops to make them updateable (you have to modify the XML behind the designer, etc.)

Stored procedures are not an option in our situation.